# Polygon tessellation library

Tags: open-source, library, c++

For a project I'm working on I need to be able to split arbitrary polygons (concave or convex) into triangles for rendering.

The concave polygons are the most problematic so I'm looking for a library that can at least split concave polygons into convex ones. I need it to be for C++, Open Source and I'd prefer it if it plays nice with `boost::geometry`.

Comment: Nice looking - unfortunately I have done pretty much no geometry (well some interaction with PyFFI's geometry methods but I wasn't writing anything that was actually doing geom calculation) so I don't know anything that can do that.

Comment: Please comment if [Delaunay triangulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation) is what you need.

Comment: @DeerHunter At first glance it seems a [constrained delaynay triangulation](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/triangle.delaunay.html) looks like it could fit the bill but I'd have to do some more research to be sure.

Comment: CGAL (or extensions) may have some functions polygon tessellation. I'm not sure that it will play nice with Boost though...

Comment: Here is an old list of triangulation algorithms and code that may help: http://vterrain.org/Implementation/Libs/triangulate.html